# Razor Html Helpers Actionlink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm learning ASP.NET MVC and I can't figure out how to add a text or an image to an actionlink. I guess I need to use Html Helpers inside Html Helpers!?

This is what I'm using right now:

Images:

```
<img src="~/Content/Images/Categories/@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.ImageFileName)" alt="@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Name)" />
```

and headlines:

```
<h2>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Name)</h2>
```

My goal is to insert the H2 tag inside an Action link in one row and the image tag inside another Actionlink.

I have tested all kinds of combinations of these examples, but I get red lines below text and it's not working:

```
@Html.ActionLink(Html.DisplayNameFor(model => item.Name).ToHtmlString(), "SortFirstName"
```

or this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit Record", "Edit", new { Id = 3 })
```

I just want the option to click on the text inside the Headline or the Image and then get to the Controller: `WebShop/ShowProducts` + the Category ID

Preciate if I can get some help with this to be able to continue with my project.

Comment: You cannot do that with `ActionLink()`. You can however use `<a href="@Url.Action(...)"><h2>...</h2></a>`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Sorry if this is a duplicate! I couldn't find the correct info. Your example could work, but I have some problem when I add this: model => item.Name for the id that I want to pass to the action method?

Comment: No sure, I assume you mean `<a href="@Url.Action("Edit", new { id = Model.Name })">...` (or `new { id = item.Name }` is this is in a loop

Comment: Thanks for the help!